# How to set ApplicationMailer (or ActionMailer) to use Activejob/sidekiq by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, sidekiq, rails-activejob

We need to use sidekiq to send all our Rails 5 emails, I found multiple links ([link #1](https://gist.github.com/maxivak/690e6c353f65a86a4af9), [link #2](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#calling-the-mailer)) showing how we can do this for specific new mailers but there is no resources on how this can be done as a default (overriding the behavior for  ApplicationMailer (or ActionMailer))

I could acheive this for devise emails using ***devise_async*** gem but I want to make this the default behavoir for all email sending across the application

So how can I chain the `deliver_later` method to the default mailer or inject a sidekiq job to be always used by the default mailer?

I have tried a few variations of adding the `deliver_later` method to the `application_mailer.rb` but none of them worked

**Update:**

I want to override `ApplicationMailer` or `ActionMailer` to avoid calling `deliver_later` for every Mailer seperately, the goal is to do this in the parent class that all mailers inherit from to avoid repeatition & maintain the DRY principle

I am expecting an update to this file `application_mailer.rb`

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'xxxxxx'
  layout 'mailer'

  # Maybe adding a way here to chain the deliver_later method
  def initialize
    # somehow chain deliver_later method after the object creation from this class
  end
end
```

Comment: There's a bit of setup involved, but following https://gist.github.com/maxivak/690e6c353f65a86a4af9 should help

Comment: Thanks Mark, unfortunately this is one of the links I meant, here he talks on a newly created mailer basis , not a global configuration for `ActionMailer` or `ApplicationMailer` classes

Comment: Ah my bad - it looks like the below answer should sort it :)

Comment: Unfortuantely Ahmed is saying the same solution you said :) I wanna override the default of the `ApplicationMailer` to avoid doing this for each mailer seperately, I will clarify the question further

Answer (score 3):

As long as you use #deliver_later and Active Job is set up to use Sidekiq it will send emails asynchronously (your emails sent in a background job) using sidekiq.

This is how you can set Active Job adapter to :sidekiq, in `config/application.rb`:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  # ...
  config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
end
```

Then start sidekiq:

```
bundle exec sidekiq -q default -q mailers
```

and your async mails will show up on the queue

```
UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_later
```

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed, this still solves the issues on a per-mailer basis, I want to override the default behavior of the `ApplicationMailer` that is inherited in all the mailers

I will clarify the question but this answer doesn't solve the question & so please remove it

Comment: But the thing is, this solution has nothing to do with any particular mailer, and it's indeed should take effect on the `ApplicationMailer`, as the `deliver_later` method is on `ActionMailer` and its the one doing the work

Comment: Tell us how this is solving one specific mailer?

Comment: Check out the links in the updated question, your solution is for a new class created `UserMailer`, if I create `CustomerMailer` it won't be affected by your solution

Comment: Ahmed, your solution is on UserMailer not ApplicationMailer , specifically: `UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_later` , I am asking for a generic way to chain this call automatically for all the mailers

Comment: No, as long as you  inherited from `ApplicationMailer` it will work on any new mailer unless you are overriding the mailer logic on every mailer

Comment: oh, you want to avoid calling `deliver_later`, but why? and you want to call what instead of it?

Comment: Exactly, I want to chain the `deliver_later` to all mailers, that is the question. because for me that is the sensible default & I want to enforce it. always.

Comment: But you can do that by going through all your code and change `deliver` to `deliver_later` and you are done, without monkey patching anything.

Comment: The point is not to monkey patch it, I want to use the async delievery by default, in the most standard possible way (if there is), otherwise I will (of course) have to use `deliver_later` as you said

Comment: The most standard way is there, and it's straight forward and plain English, use `deliver_later` ineasted of `deliver`, Every library you will use will expect this scenario and nothing else.